# Store Parse Files to Amazon S3 using iOS Swift XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have hosted my own Parse Server on Heroku. I am adding files to a Parse table column and want to save to my own S3,
I have followed the guide, 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Storing-Files-in-AWS-S3

- I created my own bucket, created my user, created my policy, attached my policy to my user
- Edited my Parse server deployment on Heroku to point to a new filesAdapter

But the following code is still saving the file to MongoDB(GridStore), is there anything else needed to be done to start using my own S3?

```
let myImage : UIImage = UIImage(named:"bird")!
let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)!
let imageFile: PFFile = PFFile(name: "bird.png", data: imageData)!
let pfuser = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
pfuser.setObject("sample text", forKey: "textcol")
pfuser.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "image")
pfuser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
print("Object has been saved.")
}
```

Thank you!